# ag-grid cell edit isCancelBeforeStart not working for popup editors

Tags: ag-grid

Cell editors in ag-grid have recently received an update that allowed for the ability to not start the editor based on certain conditions (using isCancelBeforeStart).

While it appears to work on editors which are non-popup type, it does not appear to work on popup type editors. So if isPopup() returns true, isCancelBeforeStart() never even gets called. If isPopup() returns false, then it works as expected.

The following jsfiddle shows the behavior on the numeric column https://jsfiddle.net/knhsrLxd/4/

When NumericCellEditor's isPopup() returns false:

```
NumericCellEditor.prototype.isPopup = function () { return false }
```

isCancelBeforeStart() works fine and edit is only triggered on numeric buttons.

When we change isPopup() to true:

```
NumericCellEditor.prototype.isPopup = function () { return true }
```

Observe that isCancelBeforeStart never triggers, and you can initialize edit with ANY button press. Not just numbers.

I am wondering if there is something I missed to get popup editors to trigger and honor the isCancelBeforeStart callback.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug, and was fixed yesterday (30 June 16)

See the commit in GitHub here: https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/commit/9cb2e60e353509db0b7087a771c729a46d3e7c92